# How to handle hard coded values in hive group by

Tags: sql, group-by, hive, hql

I am running something like this and getting an error.  Do I have to create the field in a separate query so I can call the field rather than the hardcoded values, or is there another way around this without the extra step?

```
SELECT FIELD_A
, 'NA' AS FIELD_B
, 'NA' AS FIELD_C
, MAX(PRICE) AS MAX_PRICE 
from table_xyz  
GROUP BY field_a
, 'NA'    
, 'NA'
;
```

Error:

> OK FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10021]: Line 74:2 Repeated key in GROUP BY ''NA''

Comment: 'NA' is not a field name. Why not just `group by field_a, field_b, field_c` or even `group by 1, 2, 3`?

Comment: In hive (at least the version we have) you can't use numbers or aliases in the group by.  So I'm thinking my only option is to create a separate table or subquery so I can name the field & then group by that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `common table expression` to do this.

```
with t1 as 
(SELECT FIELD_A
, 'NA' AS FIELD_B
, 'NA' AS FIELD_C
, PRICE
from table_xyz)
select field_a, field_b, field_c, max(price) from t1
group by field_a, field_b, field_c
```

Or you can simply do

```
SELECT FIELD_A
, 'NA' AS FIELD_B
, 'NA' AS FIELD_C
, MAX(PRICE) AS MAX_PRICE 
from table_xyz  
GROUP BY field_a, 'NA'
```

as both `field_b` and `field_c` are `NA`.

Comment: I should have made a more specific example, wince my NA fields are actually separated by other fields.  I am running a bunch of versions & unioning them together, so each version has different NA fields.  BUT, I just put one NA in there and it seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

You just can remove the 'NA' from the group by is redundant.

```
    SELECT FIELD_A
       , 'NA' AS FIELD_B
       , 'NA' AS FIELD_C
       , MAX(PRICE) AS MAX_PRICE 
    from table_xyz  
    GROUP BY field_a
```